# Decorators: TypeError: "got multiple values for keyword argument <variable name>" on function call

Tags: python, functional-programming, decorator, python-decorators

I've got a decorator that takes an authToken and provides functions which it decorates with a user_id. The idea is to stop every function that is user specific from having to look up their user object.

I've used *pargs and **kwargs to make the decorators generic and work with functions with any other parameters.

However, when I call a decorated function with more than just the parameter that is set by the decorator, I get the error: `TypeError: changeUsername() got multiple values for keyword argument 'userId'`.

Does anybody know why this is happening? I've pasted a minimal example below.

```
users = ["Name_1", "Name_2", "Name_3"]

def pwapi_auth(func):
    def inner(authToken, *pargs, **kwargs):
        users = {'a':0,
                 'b':1,
                 'c':2}
        userId = users[authToken]
        return func(userId = userId, *pargs, **kwargs)
    return inner

@pwapi_auth
def getUsername(userId):
    return users[userId]

@pwapi_auth
def changeUsername(userId, newName):
    users[userId] = newName

print getUsername('b')
changeUsername('b', 'New_Person') # <-- Error occurs on this call
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your 2nd example is not working code, Can you please paste working snippet

Comment: Don't worry I've understood now - the superclass is doing some stuff to simplify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code snippet python gets confused between positional parameter and keyword parameter for userId. Append all the parameter in pargs to solve this-

```
def pwapi_auth(func):
    def inner(authToken, *pargs, **kwargs):
        # ...
        users = {'a':0,
                 'b':1,
                 'c':2}
        userId = users[authToken]
        return func(*((userId,)+pargs), **kwargs)
    return inner
>>> print getUsername('b')
Name_2
>>> changeUsername('b', 'New_Person')
>>> print getUsername('b')
New_Person
```

Comment: You don't need the list in there; just return `func(*((userId,)+pargs), **kwargs)`

Comment: Thanks for your input @zondo, I was searching for some thing similar, it's better way to do that. I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys - seems to work. My question now is: I've got the above example (added to bottom of question) that uses a Class which doesn't require editing pargs or pwargs - it just puts the userId directly into the returned function as a positional parameter. Why does that work, and my original example does not?

Comment: `*((userId,)+pargs)` is equivalent to (and uglier than) `*(userId, *pargs)` @zondo